# How to preg_replace repeating symbol?

Tags: php, regex

I have a html content. After i use code like

```
preg_match('/adm-list-table-cell.*\"del\".*\<\/td/', $content, $zzz);
$new_string = preg_replace('/(\s\/\s)/','',$zzz[0]);
$content = str_replace($zzz[0], $new_string, $content);
```

for search string  `/  /  /  / ALL /  /  /  /  /  /  /  /  /  /`  and delete all `/` from it. how can i do it with only one preg_replace function?
[link on regex](https://regex101.com/r/yCDvKE/1)

Comment: try this `preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$zzz[0]);`

Comment: Do you really expect to find `adm-list-table-cell` in a `/  /  /  / <span class="del">ALL</span> /  /  /  /  /  /  /  /  /  /` string?

Comment: [Parsing HTML with a regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/8913537)

Comment: And why not `trim($string, ' /')`?

Comment: I have a string, which after transforms into html. In this string i dont wanna replace all " / " into an empty symbol, only " / ", that contains around `span class="del"`, so i'm trying to find that span, cause i have many `adm-list-table-cell` blocks, but only few could be  with that span

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overarching recommendation on StackOverflow for parsing html is to use an html parser like DomDocument.  If you provide more information about the variability of your input text, I may be able to write up a refined DomDocument solution.

In the interim, here is a direct, single-pattern `preg_replace()` call with no unnecessary escaping, minimal capture groups, and greedy character classes for improved efficiency and brevity.

Code: ([PHP Demo](https://3v4l.org/TaNKV))  ([Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yCDvKE/3))

```
$html = <<<HTML
<td class="adm-list-table-cell align-right"><a href="iblock_element_edit.php?IBLOCK_ID=1&amp;type=news&amp;ID=2&amp;lang=ru&amp;find_section_section=-1&amp;WF=Y" title="title">2</a></td><td class="adm-list-table-cell align-left adm-list-table-cell-last"> /  /  /  / <span class="del">ALL</span> /  /  /  /  /  /  /  /  /  / </td>
HTML;

echo preg_replace('~adm-list-table-cell.*?\K[/ ]*(<span class="del".*?</span>)[/ ]*~', '$1', $html);
```

Output:

```
<td class="adm-list-table-cell align-right"><a href="iblock_element_edit.php?IBLOCK_ID=1&amp;type=news&amp;ID=2&amp;lang=ru&amp;find_section_section=-1&amp;WF=Y" title="title">2</a></td><td class="adm-list-table-cell align-left adm-list-table-cell-last"><span class="del">ALL</span></td>
```

`\K` is used to "restart" the fullstring match -- so that the preceding element is not destroyed during replacement.

Using lazy quantifiers on the any-character dots (`.*?`) are important to avoid "flying passed" your targeted substring in your *real* content.

The forward slashes and spaces are written as a character class with a zero or more quantifier in case the the target substring does not require trimming.

p.s. ...If I can find time to write a DomDocument solution, I'll edit my answer. (but for now I must return to my work)

Answer (score 0):

this preg pattern will remove all `/` in string:

```
$content = preg_replace('/(adm-list-table-cell[^>]*>)\\s(?:\\/\s+)+(<span class="del".*<\\/span>)\\s(?:\\/\\s+)+(<)/', '${1}${2}${3}', $content);
```

https://regex101.com/r/yCDvKE/2